# Border-radius on list elements?

Tags: css

I would like to add a border radius to a list of items but I don't want each item to have the style applied to it. Right now my style has the odd list elements with one color and the even elements a darker color. When I apply the border-radius to the li it is visible for each row but I only want the first item and the last item to have this be applied to. How do I make this happen without making a special id or class for only those two list items?

Here is my HTML and CSS:

```
<section id="list">
<ul>
        <li>Song 1</li>
        <li>Song 2</li>
        <li>Song 3</li>
    </ul>
</section>

ul{
list-style:none;
padding-left:0px;
width:600px;
}

ul li:nth-child(odd){
background: rgba(12,147,0,0.4);
}

ul li:nth-child(even){
background: rgba(12,147,0,0.7);
}

li{
padding:15px;
border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Your first `ul li:nth-child(even)` was meant to be `ul li:nth-child(even):hover`, I'm sure. In fact, the two hover rules could simply be condensed to the selector `ul li:hover`.

Comment: As for border radii, do you mean you just want the top and bottom corners of the entire list to be rounded?

Comment: The first part of your answer is irrelevant since I put in the wrong code and have since edited my post. But yes, I want the top and bottom corners of the list as a whole to be rounded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [`:first-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-child-pseudo) and [`:last-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#last-child-pseudo)

```
li:first-child, li:last-child{
    padding:15px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you should just apply the pseudo-classes like that. The result is very awkward: http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/AQYTF

Comment: You both helped me figure it out. If written like this:             li{
    padding:15px;
}
li:first-child{
   border-top-left-radius:20px;
   border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    
}
li:last-child{

border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
}